# Querying & Manipulating Data located in Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to make my own DB with data pulled from a Javascript Variable located on this URL (https://www.numberfire.com/nba/fantasy/fantasy-basketball-projections/). Since the data is only made available in the variable (NF_DATA), I'm not able to easily query as I would an API.

I'm able to pull the data as I would any JSON object using the Chrome Developer Console as such:

[image: Chrome Developer Console Query]

I would like to be able to pull data with a Python script in the same way as I was doing in the Chrome Developer Console. (For instance, identifying the exact data by writing 'NF_DATA['daily_projections']['1'][...]' in the script, so I can do the manipulation directly in the script, not in Chrome Devtools). Any recommendations on how I do this? I have tried using BeautifulSoup in Python, but was having trouble grabbing the data without making the complete output into a string (would this even be a good way to think about it??)

Comment: That's not a "JSON object." It's just an object. JSON is a *textual* notation for data interchange.

Comment: What do you mean "do the same thing"? You've never said what you're trying to do, what your context is, where the data is coming from, etc. How can you expect people to help you? It's like "Can you tell me how to get to the library?" without saying A) Where you are, and B) Which library you want.

Comment: Thanks. I would be pulling the data from those objects, but this was just a high level example.

Comment: So right now I am only able to do this with the Chrome Developer Console. I would rather write a script using Python (or Node) to make the query. Does that make sense?

Comment: Do ***what***? No, it doesn't make sense. Step back, and think: Assume you know *nothing* about the situation, is the question really sufficient to explain what you want? (Hint: No, not remotely. Use the "edit" link to add a **lot** more detail.)

Comment: In addition to @T.J.Crowder's questions, it seems you're trying to manipulate client-side variables with server-side programs, right?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder See edits above, hopefully this helps clarify.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD Yes, this is the case. I was using Python since that is what I have experience with, but wouldn't be opposed to using another language if preferable.

Comment: "Pulled" how? Seriously, just stop and think about it. You're assuming all kinds of context.

Comment: I appreciate your help here @T.J.Crowder - I'm able to manipulate data located in the javascript variable using the console provided by Chrome DevTools, and an example of me doing that is shown in the screenshot located above. You can do this too if you go to that URL and use the console located in devtools. Rather than using the console to do this, I would like to write a script (either in javascript or python, whichever more appropriate) so I can use the data in my program. If that's not clear, I'm happy to answer further questions.

Comment: Perhaps for the sake of this exercise, how would I do the same exact query shown in the screenshot above in a python or javascript file